# Running a Java application on Weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, weblogic, ear

I have a Java application consisting of multiple nested EAR projects with application.xml and Ant build scripts. Although I have the source code for all the modules, I do not have any .project files. I need to run this application on Weblogic, which is the server it runs on in production. I do have access to the Weblogic server (version 10.3.6) in production, but I do not know what parameters to read and transfer in my local IDE (Eclipse). I only know how to configure the datasource on it (an Oracle DB).

Can anyone provide me with a "how-to-for-dummies" guide to follow for all the projects I inherited without any documentation? I need to maintain the code and implement some minor changes.

Thanks in advance.